# VPS zlib.output_compression for Wordpress, should I enable?

Tags: php, wordpress, compression, vps

Should I enable **zlib.output_compression** if I'm running WP on VPS?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I actually read this document before posting, which is why my question is precise and to the point.